# JavaScript/jQuery --> How to add thousand separator to 'Total value?'

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

How to add thousand separator to 'Total value?' so that it looks like 1 000, or 23 000 --> with blank space between thousands and hundreds, not coma but blank space... 
Also when I write into INPUT 5-digit number the total value disappears...

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qh1L7bk5/53/)

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="nazwa"  min="0" max="500000"  >
<br><br>
Total value: <span id="total_expenses1"></span>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
$('#nazwa').keyup(function(){ // run anytime the value changes
    var raz = document.getElementById('nazwa');
    var dwa = document.getElementById('total_expenses1');
    var firstValue  = Number($('#nazwa').val());   // get value of field
    var secondValue = 1.15; // convert it to a float
    raz.value = THOUSAND_SEPARATOR(this.value);
    var mega = $('#total_expenses1').html(Math.ceil(firstValue * secondValue));  
    THOUSAND_SEPARATOR(mega.value);
    // add them and output it
});
```

As for now thousand separator function works only for input value

Comment: I dont see any use of `var raz = document.getElementById('nazwa');
  var dwa = document.getElementById('total_expenses1');` in your code

Comment: raz.value = THOUSAND_SEPARATOR(this.value);

Comment: do you want it like this 123,456? this regular expression might help .replace(/(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,')

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined` -- `bilangan` is undefined. What is your intended purpose of total value?

Comment: I want Total value to look like this: 1 000 or 23 444

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('total_expenses1').innerHTML = THOUSAND_SEPARATOR(String(Math.ceil(Number((this.value || '').replace(/\s/g, '')) * secondValue)));
```